# iPhone: iOS 4.3 SDK Simulators stuck up and crashing:

Tags: iphone

I have updated my Mac to 10.6.7 with Xcode 4. I am trying to build and run some projects which has downloaded from Internet. I set the deployment target as 4.1/4.2/4.3 and device family as 'iPhone' and trying to build and run the application in Simulator. For ex: i downloaded a project from the following link from GitHub:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/

I set the deployment target as 4.1 or 4.2 or 4.3 and device family as 'iPhone' and trying to build and run the application in Simulator. But Simulator launches and stuck up infinitely. I had to do force quit of simulator, i checked so many times, but the same result. But at the same time, i'm able to build and run some other my projects without any issues. This is happening only for few projects when i run. 
What could be the reason here? Is there any settings that i need to make-up?

Please advise me.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Try Debugging by putting breakpoints in AppDelegate and your first view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trash your **/Users/{Your name}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/** directory and rebuild the projects you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thank u  todd it helpful to me.. *Make Sure we put a copy of* ***"User's"*** folder existed in ***iPhone Simulator*** folder

Answer (score 0):

@Kirby Todd Answer perfectly  correct with a small change

[notifications doesn't show/ doesn't scheduled in Simulator but works in device Problm on Simulator 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431086/notifications-doesnt-show-doesnt-scheduled-in-simulator-but-works-in-device-p/10431559#10431559)

*Make Sure we put a copy of* "**User's"** folder existed in **iPhone Simulator folder**

Thank U @Kirby Todd