# notifications doesn't show/ doesn't scheduled in Simulator but works in device Problem on Simulator 4.3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator

I have Implemented a reminder application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    int count = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];  
    NSLog(@"count is %d",count);
```

**All are works fine** notification alert raises when it's scheduled time arives.

**Suddenly today notifications are not showing** . and they didn't scheduled

notifications count also remains same even i set the notification,

But ***when i exicuted the application in my device, it works perfectly, notificaton count increases, Notification alert raises perfectly***

But not work in simulator...

*Why  Notifications doesn't work on simulator..?*

I have used ***`Xcode 4.1`***

***`iPhone 4.3 simulator`***

What happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Trash your /Users/{Your name}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ directory and rebuild the projects you are having trouble with.
```

Solved by follow question [iPhone: iOS 4.3 SDK Simulators stuck up and crashing:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428576/iphone-ios-4-3-sdk-simulators-stuck-up-and-crashing)

Thank u @Kiby Todd...

*Make Sure we put a copy of* ***"User's"*** folder existed in ***iPhone Simulator*** folder

Re paste **User** Folder in ***iPhone Simulator***